# Setting specific location as center of map on reload Java script API

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I would like to set my google map to load at Medina, OH. I did find some information about the map center loading to a specific location but all it gave me was an example of Chicago.

Below is the code I change the `var map =` to `var Medina` but it doesn't work. Can someone please tell me why and how I can set it to be centered on Medina, OH on page load?

```
    function initialize() {
      var mapOptions = {
        zoom: 13,
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(40.7809919,-73.9665273)
      };

      var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
          mapOptions);
    }

    function loadScript() {
      var script = document.createElement('script');
      script.type = 'text/javascript';
      script.src = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false&' +
          'callback=initialize';
      document.body.appendChild(script);
    }

    window.onload = loadScript;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Peter said, the Latitude and Longitude coordinates need to be changed to match where you desire the center of the map to be.

The line:

```
center: new google.maps.LatLng(40.7809919,-73.9665273)
```

specifies the center of the map, Latitude, then Longitude respectively.

If you desire the center of you map to be at Latitude 30 and Longitude -80, simply change the line to

```
center: new google.maps.LatLng(30.0000000,-80.0000000)
```

This is all well and good, but you desired the center to be at Medina, Ohio. To locate the geographical coordinates for this place, we can use Google Maps, the very product you are customizing.

If you navigate to [maps.google.com](http://maps.google.com/), you can search for 'Medina, Ohio.' This will bring you to a view of the city on the map. If you *right click* on a location on the map, and select 'What's Here?' you can see the geographical coordinates for this place.

I selected a point in the center of Medina and got latitude **41.1378070** and longitude **-81.8641530**. Now that we know the coordinates, all we have to do is change the aforementioned line to:

```
center: new google.maps.LatLng(41.1378070,-81.8641530)
```

If you desire, you can select a point on the map for yourself to customize the coordinates for your map. If you have any questions, let me know!

Comment: Got it! I was thinking about it all night and thought the same thing. So this morning I looked up the coordinates. smh That was simple I don't know why I didn't figure that out sooner. Maybe just over complicating the function. Thank you so much guys!

Comment: No problem! Welcome to StackOverflow! When you believe that your question has been answered, if you get a chance, please select what you believe to be the most relevant answer by clicking the check mark next to the answer once you are logged in. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
google.maps.LatLng(40.7809919,-73.9665273)
```

These are the coordinates you got to correct so that they match your center.